# Scale of trigonometrics functions in tikz plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have been using tikz to plot different trigonometric functions, but often found a strange problem: when I write something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[domain=-4:4,samples=1000,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{cos(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd only see almost a straight line. However when I multiply the argument by a large number, say 100, something closer to the plot of a cosine function appears:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[domain=-4:4,samples=1000,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{cos(100*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The same happens with sinus. Why?

Comment: You are probably looking for `trig format=rad` since otherwise the arguments of the trigonometric functions are assumed to be in degrees. That is, something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad] \draw[domain=-4:4,samples=101,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{cos(\x)}); \end{tikzpicture}` should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the arguments of the trigonometric functions are assumed to be in degrees. You can switch to radians by either

- using the `trig format=rad` (in pgfplots use `trig format plots=rad`), or
- wrapping the argument of the function into `deg`, or
- appending the argument of the function by an `r`.

BTW, there is also the `sin` and `cos` path construction available, i.e. you do not necessarily need a `plot` to plot the trigonometric functions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw[thick,blue,trig format=rad]  plot[domain=-3*pi/2:3*pi/2,samples=101,variable=\x] ({\x},{cos(\x)})
node[right]{use \texttt{trig format=rad}};
\draw[thick,red,yshift=-1cm]  
plot[domain=-3*pi/2:3*pi/2,samples=101,variable=\x] ({\x},{cos(deg(\x))})
node[right]{use \texttt{deg} function};
\draw[thick,magenta,yshift=-2cm]  
plot[domain=-3*pi/2:3*pi/2,samples=101,variable=\x] ({\x},{cos(\x r)})
node[right]{append an \texttt{r} to the argument};
\draw[thick,orange,yshift=-3cm] (-3*pi/2,0) sin (-pi,-1) cos (-pi/2,0) sin (0,1)
 cos (pi/2,0) sin (pi,-1) cos (3*pi/2,0)
 node[right]{use \texttt{sin} and \texttt{cos} path construction};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]